# how to show a message using jquery in html when radio button is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery stuff and want to do following stuff :
I have radio button enbaled and disabled. On onchanging to enabled, my html page at bottom it can show information "radio enabled thanks".

Quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try on your own? If yes, share the code snippet.

Comment: Anything which need to be imported in html page that also please mention while answering.

Comment: <TR><TD ALIGN="LEFT" WIDTH="50%%"><B>&nbsp;&nbsp;Radio Status </B></TD><TD ALIGN="LEFT">
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="STST" VALUE="Enabled" onchange=display_msg();Checked>Enabled
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="STST" VALUE="Disabled" onchange=display_msg();>Disabled</TD></TR>

Comment: JUST tell how to show information not alert in jquery irrespective of radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    $('<p>radio enabled thanks</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: I dont want alert. It should be information to user thats it.

Comment: @CJ_world I updated it. Check it.

Comment: Irrespective of radio button. If i just wanna add this information at last of my html tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kh3Lr1ms/)

```
   $( "input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#log" ).html( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
```

Comment: This is not giving me any idea. Please refer above code

Comment: Check my fiddle you will get idea

Answer (score 1):

For jquery 1.9 or higher you can use following condition on onclick event

```
if($("#radio").prop("checked", true))
{
    $("#id").html("radio enabled thanks");
}
```

For older versions you can use

```
jQuery("#radio").attr('checked', 'checked');
```